# I do not have the extension tool bar in Visual Studio, how do I get it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I was informed the extension would be under, "view" and then it would be an extension toolbar. However, I do not see it. This is what I am trying to get.

[screenshot of visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzJHe.jpg)

Unfortunately, I do not have the, "Extensions" as an option.

Comment: What do you have then?

Comment: I have no extension at all. When I click, "view" I do not have an option for extensions.

Comment: Have you checked out the documentation at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery? Do you see the Extensions icon in the Activity Bar on the side of VS Code?